# How to Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-services

I have 3 project in my solution.

- Test Client         => for add reference and access via tcp ip
- WcfServiceLibruary1 => for executing my methots
- WindowsService1     => for installing&running as windows service(Account:Network Service , StartType:Automatic)

[image]

I used all same codes on msdn sample

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx
```

I use a wcf service that has 2 methots.I want to use this  wcf service in managed windows service.I added a windows service to my solution and set references stuff.

I use this address referance on my wcf - app.config:

```
net.tcp://localhost:2023/Service1
```

*NOW PROBLEM IS:*

I success to add reference to my test client project using

`net.tcp://localhost:2023/Service1`:

But this referance address is not be used on install as windows service !!!
When i install it as windows service,i cant access this address,
And i got this error: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

WcfServiceLibruary app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2023/Service1"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

My WindowsService :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }
    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
    myServiceHost.Open();
 }
```

Everything works well when i start on visualstudio service host:
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is. Are you saying the `app.config` file doesn't have the configuration settings once deployed? Note that the config sections need to be part of the Windows service `app.config` file, not the service library.

Comment: i copy wcf app.config to windows service project.My wcf host service doesnt work on installing as a windows service to computer.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean?  Do you get an error?  Does the service not start?  Can you not connect to the service?  If the service is running, you can enter `netstat` at the DOS prompt and it see if port 2023 is established.

Comment: When i install it as windows service,i check it using telnet localhost 2023

Comment: And i got this error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read This Article

In this Construct the service and provide the hosting code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: The example might use http, but you can easily substitute net.tcp for the binding.