# How to store a stored procedure result in cache in asp.net System.Web.Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, caching

I want to cache the result of my stored procedure `db.BIOGetETLJobs()` called by LINq for 5 minutes, then use it in other controller methods.

How to cache the result?

```
public class JobsETLController : Controller
{ 
    private ETL_REP_MAUIEntities db = new ETL_REP_MAUIEntities();
    public   ObjectResult<BIOGetETLJobs_Result> ETLJobs;

    public JobsETLController()
    {
        ETLJobs =db.BIOGetETLJobs();
    }
```

Comment: Is your intent to use the cached data across many different browser sessions?

Comment: no only i need the result for all methods in the controller

Comment: Are these controller methods controller Actions?

Comment: Actionresult and jsonresult

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to cache the results across all browser sessions, and not on the same SQL Server from which you are querying the ETL jobs in the first place, you will need a windows service running on the same PC that is running your web server that can hold the data in memory.

WCF is a good choice to communicate with the service.

Some links to get you started:

[How to Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542654/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx